# Why doesn't ClassLoader::getResource return null, but Class::getResource returns a correct one

Tags: java, class

I wrote the following simple program:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(get(Test.class.getResource("/c.conf"))); //fine
        System.out.println(
               get(Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/c.conf"))
        ); //NPE, Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/c.conf") returns null
    }

    public static String get(URL url) throws IOException {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int current;
        while ((current = reader.read()) != -1)
            sb.append((char) current);
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

So, I looked at [***the documentation***](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) of `Class::getResource(String)` and found this:

> The rules for searching resources associated with a given class are
>   implemented by the defining class loader of the class.

So I thought these two methods should have loaded the resource in the same way.

Why does `Test.class.getClassLoader().getResource("/c.conf")` throw `NullPointerException` whereas `Test.class.getResource("/c.conf")` does not?

Comment: @JonnyHenly Sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: The documentation for [`Class#getClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getClassLoader--) explains why it would return `null`.

Comment: can you run the command `tree` or equivalent on your project and add to question (curious where the resource file is relative to your class)